# R Shiny how can i updateProgressBar inside a function?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets, r-environment

I'm new here, sorry for any mistakes.

I have the following code working:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

#### Header ####
header <- dashboardHeader()

#### Sidebar ####
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

#### Body ####
body <- dashboardBody(
  actionButton("go", label = "Go!"),
  # Loading Bar
  progressBar("progress", value=0, total=100, title="", display_pct = TRUE)
)

ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

#### Server ####
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    for(i in 1:13){
      updateProgressBar(
        session = session,
        id = "progress",
        value = i,
        total = 13,
        title = paste("Progress ", i, "/", 13)
      )
      Sys.sleep(0.2)
    }
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But now I need to update the progressBar by some code inside a function already defined (in a source code, in fact). As a test I defined:

```
test_func <- function(){
  for(i in 1:13){
    updateProgressBar(
      session = session,
      id = "progress",
      value = i,
      total = 13,
      title = paste("Progress ", i, "/", 13)
    )
    Sys.sleep(0.2)
  }
}
```

And edited the server to:

```
#### Server ####
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    test_func()
    }
  )
}
```

I get the following error:
"object type closure is not subsettable"

How can I do it in the right way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be down to environments.

I get an error (different to yours) when I define `test_func` *outside* the server function.  When I define it *inside* the server function, I get the expected behaviour.  Can you source your external file inside the server function?

If not, pass `session` as an argument to `test_func`.  When I did that, and defined `test_func`  outside the server function, everything worked as expected.